# Blazor url always starting in https://localhost:5001http://localhost:5000 what's the problem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, visual-studio-mac

I Can't configure it when I delete it and paste my own, after running it is giving me an error like in the image below and when I check the url is https://localhost:5001http://localhost:5000 how to fix that? Thanks a lot

[image: The error and the option's page]

Comment: Do you have a `launchSettings.json` file? If so, what's in there?

Comment: Yes I have,and finally I solved the problem by changing it but I can't delete my post maybe I can answer myself somehow? :/

Comment: You should be able to post an answer of your own. Alternatively, if Data Juggler delete's their answer, you'll be able to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed that problem as mentioned @Kirk Larkin I went to `lunchSettings.json` and changed there the applicationUrl

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but try semicolon delimiter or comma delimiter, or just http://localhost 5000.

```
https://localhost:5001;http://localhost5000
```

Or maybe:

```
https://localhost:5001,http://localhost5000
```

Or try just one:

```
http://localhost5000
```

Comment: I can't change it whenever I change it and press ok then I return and see that it's the same invalid url :///

Comment: Ok, sorry. I am not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things to start with unsecure protocol http:

1. Remove the part https://localhost:7248 from launchSettings.json uner Properties folder both from Client and Server Project.
2. Comment the line app.UseHttpsRedirection() from the Program.cs under the Server Project

Also you need to know how you start the Blazor in order this changes to take an effect. Do not start it with IIS Profile but instead with Server profile. Try via Microsoft Visual Studio if it is possible.